# What is the difference between current_page_parent and current_page_ancestor?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, menus

In the function `wp_page_menu` there is an auto-generated `classes` to the list elements and the function generates `current_page_parent` and `current_page_ancestor` to a parent menu item if I clicked a child menu item (I mean if the current page is the child menu element). So now why does WordPress generate two different classes for the same element.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These classes are explained a bit more on the page for [`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#more-information). But the words 'parent' and 'ancestor' give it away already.

A parent is an ancestor. A grandparent is also an ancestor, but not a parent.

If your hierarchy is only two deep, there will only be parents and children. So in that case all parents are ancestors and the two classes have the same effect. But when your hierarchy is deeper, the two classes get different meanings.

Comment: Yes, Thanks man. Actually wordpress didn't state that properly